# modal popup in javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, popup

I have a checkbox, which is inside a modal popup div.I want the check box value when the checkbox is checked and want to place the value to a div which is outside the modal popup box.Please help me to find a solution.
Please find the code below

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="test"></div> 
    <h2>Modal popup</h2> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button> 
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"> 
        <div class="modal-body"> 
            <input type="checkbox" class="ck " id="mealstotal" value="12"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="modal-footer"> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: post your own code first , please.

Comment: <div class="container">
<div id="test"></div>
  <h2>Modal popup</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   
        <div class="modal-body">
         <input type="checkbox" class="ck " id="mealstotal" value="12">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
I want the check box value inside test div

Comment: Get the value and store in a var like `$("#chkbox").is(":checked")` and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below mentioned solution. This will help you.

```js
$(document).on('change','#item',function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
      $('#result').html($(this).val());
   }else{
      $('#result').html('');
   }
});
```

```css
div {border:1px solid red; width:100%; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="item" id="item" value="1" /> Checkbox

<div id="result"></div>
```

Let me know if it not works.